# How do I run a Bazel test target exclusively with a sandbox?

Tags: bazel

I want to run a test target that runs exclusively. However, according to https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html#common.tags, if I use the "exclusive" tag, then the target will not run with sandboxing. Sometimes, a child process that's spawned as a part of running the test target will not terminate. I want to ensure that the child process terminates.

Comment: I realize that one option would be to add "cpu:100" to the test target's tag list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intent here was to ensure that child processes do not continue living once the Bazel target was complete. Since I was running without Bazel sandboxing, I could not take advantage of the Bazel's sandboxing capabilities to ensure that child processes actually were terminated.

Fortunately, my tests were intended for a Linux system, so I wanted to use Linux's process namespace feature to ensure that the child processes were terminated. I used the [`unshare` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html) to set up a process namespace before running my Bazel command:

```
$ bazel shutdown # ensure Bazel not already running
$ unshare --pid --fork --map-root-user bazel test ...
```

I think the lesson here is that even though Bazel also uses Linux namespaces to set up Bazel sandboxes, Bazel's sandboxing capabilities are either all-or-nothing (e.g. you use many Linux namespaces or no Linux namespaces).